# NodeJS Object Casting with defaults and removing extra keys

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ecmascript-6, es6-class

Assuming somewhere in NodeJS backend code, we have this object:

```
{
  name : "foo"
  secret : "bar"
}
```

We want to return this object as JSON in response of an HTTP request, but, we don't want it to have the secret, i.e. the return object must be:

```
{
  name : "foo"
}
```

Assume we are using the latest NodeJS and we can use any 3rd party npm package.

Bonus for default params, for example, what if we want the returned object to always include "age", if it's not present, then set it to `0`

```
{
  name : "foo"
  age  : 0
}
```

---

EDIT: To add more context, I am not just trying to remove one particular elements, there could be more unwanted elements:

```
{
  name : "foo"
  secret1 : "bar"
  secret2 : "bar"
  secret3 : "bar"
  someSecretThatIdontKnowTheirNameYet : "bar"
}
```

I just have a prototype, or class, or whatever which says:

```
{
   name: String, required
   age: Number, required
}
```

I am trying to figure what this unknown thing above is. Looking for something like:

```
cleanedUpObject = clean(rawObject, prototypeOrClassOrSomeOtherThing)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a function, and [destructure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Object_destructuring) the object. You can set [default values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Default_values_2) on specific properties. Then you can return a new object with the properties you want.

```js
const formatResponse = ({ name, age = 0 }) => ({
  name,
  age,
});

const data = {
  name : "foo",
  secret1 : "bar",
  secret2 : "bar",
  secret3 : "bar",
  someSecretThatIdontKnowTheirNameYet : "bar"
};

console.log(formatResponse(data));
```

Another option is to reduce the model, and include only the properties that exist in the model. If a property is not found on the object, take the default from the model.

```js
const model = {
  name: 'baz',
  age: 0
}

const formatResponse = (o) =>
  Object.entries(model)
  .reduce((r, [k, v]) => {
    r[k] = k in o ? o[k] : v;

    return r;
  }, {});

const data = {
  name: "foo",
  secret1: "bar",
  secret2: "bar",
  secret3: "bar",
  someSecretThatIdontKnowTheirNameYet: "bar"
};

console.log(formatResponse(data));
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove private fields from your data and append default value:

```
const BLACK_LIST_FIELDS = ["secret"];
const DEFAULT_FIELDS_MAP = {
  age: 0,
};
function getResponse(data) {
  let safeRes = Object.assign({}, data);
  BACK_LIST_FIELDS.forEach((key) => delete safeRes[key]);
  Object.keys(DEFAULT_FIELDS_MAP).forEach((key) => {
    if (!safeRes[key]) {
      safeRes[key] = DEFAULT_FIELDS_MAP[key];
    }
  });
  return safeRes;
}

const data = {
  name : "foo",
  secret : "bar",
};

console.log(getResponse(data));
```

Result: { name: 'foo', age: 0 }

Answer (score 0):

best two options I can think of:

### toJSON

```js
const o = {
  name : "foo",
  secret : "bar",
  toJSON() {
    return {
      name: this.name
    }
  }
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(o));
```

you can return what you want from toJSON, for more info read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#toJSON()_behavior

### Symbol

```js
const secret = Symbol('secret');
const o = {
  name : "foo",
  [secret]: "bar"
};

console.log(JSON.stringify(o));
console.log(o[secret]);
```

for more info on Symbol read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol

Answer (score 0):

Here’s what I understand from your question:

- you have an Object that defines the keys and types of your expected result.
  You call this `prototypeOrClassOrSomeOtherThing`. Let’s call this **definition**, for short (since boh `prototype` and `class` have a defined meaning in JS)
- you have another Object that contains a certain function result. Let’s call this **input**.
- you want an Object that consists of *only* those keys and values from `input` that are defined in `definition`.
- In case `input` does not contain a key/value that's defined in `definition`, use a reasonable default value based on the type defined in `definition`.

## Strategy

- we’ll write a function `defaultsFromDefinition` that creates an object with default values as defined by `definition`
- we then call this function to start out with an object of default values, `cleanedUpObject`
- next we replace this object's values with values from `input` if and only if `input` has a matching key/value pair
- profit

## Code

```js
function defaultsFromDefinition(
    definition,
    defaultsByType = { String: '', Number: 0 })
{
  return Object
    .entries(definition)
    .reduce((result, [key, type]) => ({
      ...result,
      [key]: defaultsByType[type.name]
    }), {})
}

function clean(input, definition) {
  const cleanedUpObject = defaultsFromDefinition(definition)
  return Object
    .keys(cleanedUpObject)
    .filter(key => input[key] !== undefined)
    .reduce((result, key) => ({
      ...result,
      [key]: input[key]
    }), cleanedUpObject)
}

// ---- Test ----

const rawObject = {
  name : "foo",
  secret1 : "bar",
  secret2 : "bar",
  secret3 : "bar",
  someSecretThatIdontKnowTheirNameYet : "bar"
}

const definition = {
   name: String,
   age: Number
}

const cleanedUpObject = clean(rawObject, definition)
console.log(cleanedUpObject)
```